# Prove that if $\sum a_k z_1^k$ converges, then $\sum a_k z^k$ also converges, for $|z|<|z_1|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Show that if a power-series converges for any value of $z_{0}$ of $z$, it will be absolutely convergent for all values of $z$ whose representation points are within a circle which passes through $z_{0}$ and has its center at the origin.

**Proof Attempt**
Let z be such a point, so we have $\left| z\right| < \left| z_{0}\right| $. Now, since $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n}z_{0}^{n}$ converges,  $a_{n}z_{0}^{n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty $, so we can find M(independent of n) such that $\left| a_{n}z_{0}^{n}\right| < M$ and we observe that $\left| a_{n}z^{n}\right| < M\left| \dfrac {z} {z_{0}}\right| ^{n}$. So every term in the series $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left| a_{n}z^{n}\right| $ is less than the corresponding term in the convergent geometric series $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }M\left| \dfrac {Z} {Z_{0}}\right| ^{n}$ the series is therefore convergent and so the power-series is absolutely convergent , as the series of moduli of its terms is a convergent series. 
I am unsure how to tackle the second part(converse) of the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the "converse" you need to prove? As far as I can see, your proof is complete as it stands.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry i am new to proofs so i was under the assumption that i would need to prove something to come to the conclusion that something forms a circle than just starting with the assumption as i had.

Comment: If you want to prove "A if and only if B", then you need both directions: assume A and conclude B, then wipe the slate and assume B, conclude A (or one can do the two halves in the opposite order). However, in this case you just want to prove "if A then B", so there is only one direction to do: assume A, conclude B.

Comment: thanks for that clarification. I would try always keep that in mind.

Comment: In both cases, you're _allowed_ to replace any "assume this, conclude that" step with "assume not-that, conclude not-this" (that is, exchange the assumption and conclusion, _and_ negate both) if the latter happens to be easier to do (which depends on that "this" and "that" are). That's the _contrapositive_, a term that is sometimes confused with the "converse". But you need only to prove _either_ an implication _or_ its contrapositive -- they are logically equivalent.

Comment: (Don't worry, it becomes second nature to remember how these things fit together with a bit of practice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're saying is the following.

> If a power series converges for a number $z=z_0\neq0$ then it will converge absolutely for any $z$ such that $|z|<|z_0|$.

The idea is that since $\sum a_k z_0^k$ converges then $a_k z_0^k\to0$. Then, for some $n\geq N$ we have that $|a_n z_0^n| < 1$. Let $C$ be a circle with radius $0< R < |z_1|$. Then if $z\in C$ and $n\geq N$ we have that $|z| \leq R$ and

$$|a_n z^n|=|a_n z_0^n|\left|\frac{z^n}{z_0^n}\right|<\left|\frac{z^n}{z_0^n}\right|\leq \left|\frac{R}{z_0 }\right|^n=q^n$$

Since $0<q<1$,  $\sum a_k z^k$ is dominated by  $\sum q^k$, so that by Weierstrass' $M$ criterion, the original series converges absolutely and uniformly in $C$.

---

**ADD:** You might also want to prove the following (by contraposition):

> If a power series diverges for a number $z=z_0\neq0$ then it will diverge for any $z$ such that $|z|>|z_0|$.

Comment: Thanks so much mate that was very helpful.

Comment: @Hardy Anytime! Glad to help.